# Javascript wrong outcome when crafting a custom regex camelCase solution for strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, ternary-operator

I'm attempting a Javascript challenge who's instructions are:

```
 Complete the method/function so that it converts dash/underscore delimited 
 words into camel casing. The first word within the output should be    
 capitalized only if the original word was capitalized.

Examples:
toCamelCase("the-stealth-warrior")
// returns "theStealthWarrior"

toCamelCase("The_Stealth_Warrior")
// returns "TheStealthWarrior"
```

My solution is:

```
function toCamelCase(str) {
  console.log(str);
  var camel = str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|-\w|_\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index === 0 && letter === letter.toLowercase  ? 
  letter.toLowercase : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/(-|_)/g, "");
  console.log(camel);
  return camel;
}
```

and the output when using my code with the test cases is:

```
toCamelCase('the_stealth_warrior') did not return correct value - 
Expected: theStealthWarrior, instead got: TheStealthWarrior
```

any ideas where this is going wrong? I feel my conditions in the ternary operator should be returning a lowercase t.

Comment: I'm confused. That second example in the instructions is not camelCase...

Comment: [It seems working](http://jsfiddle.net/xy47jdfp/) after fixing the lowercase issue. (I optimized the regex a bit).

Comment: @crush whoops! now I see it, and I can see that it doesn't like it either, Javascript was covering up my mistake and still returning a value before

Comment: Why use regular expressions on this? The instructions don't seem to call for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit of code here is causing your problem:

```
function(letter, index) {
    return index === 0 && letter === letter.toLowercase  ? 
        letter.toLowercase : letter.toUpperCase();
}
```

You probably meant to use `toLowerCase()`, but instead you've provided a reference to a non-existent property of `letter`. Since `toLowercase` doesn't exist, it will return `undefined` which will cause your conditional to always return false.

Change the line to:

```
function(letter, index) {
    return index === 0 && letter === letter.toLowerCase()  ? 
        letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about simplifying it a bit to this:

```js
function toCamelCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/[-_](.?)/g, function(match, p1) {
        return p1.toUpperCase();
    })
}

document.write(toCamelCase("the-stealth-warrior") + "<br>");


document.write(toCamelCase("The_Stealth_Warrior")  + "<br>");
```

**Explanation:**

`[-_]` Find either a `-` or `_`

`(.?)` Followed by any other character and put this other character in a group.

Then call `.replace()` on that with a custom callback using the `g` flag to do all matches.

The custom callback will be passed the full match as the first argument and any groups in the match as the subsequent arguments.  Since what we want to convert this to is just the uppercase version of the first group, we just uppercase the second argument with `return p1.toUpperCase()` and then the whole match is replaced by an upper case version of the first matched group.  This then converts `_x` to `X`.

This skips the leading character because there's no `-` or `_` before it.

This skips any trailing `-` or `_` because there's no character after it.